# Yaws files not rendering correctly

Tags: html, ubuntu, erlang, yaws

I downloaded Yaws on Ubuntu 19.04, cloned klacke's project, and configured my `/etc/yaws/yaws.config` to point to that project.

When I create a new `.yaws` file and access `localhost:port/page_name.yaws`, it returns the raw code like:

```
method(Arg) -> Rec = Arg#arg.req, Rec#http_request.method.
out(Arg) -> {ehtml, f("Method: ~s" , [method(Arg)])}.
```

on my browser. I have even tried to wrap everything within "html" tags, but it still fails to render properly.

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `<erl>` and `</erl>` tags around your code. Try this instead:

```
<erl>
method(Arg) ->
    Rec = Arg#arg.req, Rec#http_request.method.
out(Arg) ->
    {ehtml, f("Method: ~s" , [method(Arg)])}.
</erl>
```

Fetching the page with the tags properly in place produces this result:

```
Method: GET
```